# Limit of a particular integral.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, analysis, epsilon-delta

Let $f_{t}(x)$ be a compactly supported positive function for all $t\geq 0$.
If we know that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}f_{t}(x)$ does not exist for all $x$ (i.e. point-wise), can it be shown that
$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\int f_{t}(x)dx$ does not exist?

If the answer is no, what would be the necessary and sufficient conditions on $f_{t}(x)$ so that the answer is affirmative?

It seems that the key is to prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $t^{'}$ such that for all $t^{'}$ such that for all $x$ in the support of $f_{t^{'}}(x)$  we have $f_{t^{'}}(x)>\frac{\varepsilon}{\mathbf{supp}\big(f_{t^{'}}(x)\big)}$. With the latter, it can then be shown that

$$
\int f_{t^{'}}(x)dx>\varepsilon
$$

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There are counterexamples:

Consider $f_t(x)=t+1$ if $0\leq x\leq1/(t+1)$ and $0$ otherwise, then $f_t\geq0$ is compactly supported and $\lim_{t\to\infty}f_t(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in$ **supp**$(f_t)$, but $\int f_t(x)=1$ for all $t\geq0$.

---

There exist many sufficient conditions, here is an easy one: if $f_t\geq0$ for all $t$ and there exists a positive-measure set $S$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f_t(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in S$, then
$$\int f_t(x)dx\geq|S|\inf_{x\in S}f_t(x)\to\infty\ \ \text{as}\ \ t\to\infty.$$

Note that this is clearly not necessary. In fact, I feel it's quite hopeless to find necessary and sufficient conditions since the setting is too general.

Comment: This is an interesting response. I am very grateful for your time. If I may probe further... what if I know that $f_{t}(x)= \sum_{i}a_{i}e^{-it(x-y)\lambda_{i}}$, where $\sum_{i=1}|a_{i}|^{2}<\infty$ and $\lambda_{i}$ are arbitrary (If you recognize this as a quasipreriodic function then you are getting the flavour of where I am going with this).

Comment: @Hldngpk Just to confirm, the $i$ before $t(x-y)$ in the exponential is the complex unit right? Not the summation index $i$? Also, what would be the integral range in this case? I mean the bounds $a,b$ in $\int_a^bf_t(x)dx$.

Comment: indeed the i in the exponential is $\sqrt{-1}$. The integral is actually a double intebral of the form $\int_{a_{1}}^{b_{1}}\int_{a_{2}}^{b_{2}}f_{t}(x-y)dxdy$. $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}$ and $a_{4}$ are any real numbers. I made a mistake writing the series definition of $f_{t}(x-y)$. I accidentally wrote $f_{t}(x)$ on the left-hand side, but now the function is of two variables and te integral is a double integral.

Comment: So, just to clarify further. $f_{t}(x-y) = \sum_{k}a_{k}e^{-it(x-y)\lambda_{k}}$, where $\sum_{k}|a_{k}|^{2}<\infty$ and $\lambda_{k}$ are arbitrary  real numbers.